# Agrupar y sumar segun id's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataFrame con los siguientes datos

```
d = {'id': ['50', '50', '50', '12', '12', '43'],
     'id_persona': ['1', '1', '1', '23', '23', '4']
     }
```

y la salida que espero es:

```
new_d = {'id': ['50','12', '43'],
     'id_persona': ['1', '23', '4'],
    'cantidad' : [3,2,1]
     }
```

Estoy trabado en como hacer para sumar las cantidades de la tercera columna

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'id': ['50', '50', '50', '12', '12', '43'],
     'id_persona': ['1', '1', '1', '23', '23', '4']
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
new_df = df.groupby("id").agg({"id_persona": pd.Series.nunique})
```

Comment: Corrige el ejemplo porque no es reproducible. Los arreglos no son del mismo tamaño.

Comment: arreglado, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo en este caso usaré value_counts para resolver

```
df_new=pd.DataFrame(df[['id','id_persona']].value_counts()).reset_index()
df_new.rename(columns={0:'cantidad'})
```

Donde le paso a df una lista con las columnas que quiero que evalue y value_counts() contara los valores unicos de esas dos filas además se utiliza reset_index() porque con .value_counts() id y id_persona quedan como indices. el resto solo es para cambiar el nombre de la columna que contiene la suma.

Answer (score 2):

Se agrupa por `id` y se crean dos agregados: `id_persona` y `cantidad`, usando las funciones `max` y `count` respectivamente. Luego se reinicia el índice creado.

Por último se convierte a un diccionario con orientación tipo lista.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
        'id': ['50', '50', '50', '12', '12', '12', '43'],
        'id_persona': ['1', '1', '1', '23', '23', '4','4']
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

new_df = df.groupby("id") \
    .agg(id_persona=('id_persona', 'max'), cantidad=('id_persona', 'count')) \
    .reset_index()

new_df.to_dict('list')
```